# Stepping Into / Debugging Interface Implementer

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging, interface, visual-studio-debugging

I have two projects in my solution `Bridge` and `BridgeInterface` being used by my applications update process and it's throwing a FileLoadException when I try to run use the `Initialize()` method from the Bridge class.

The problem is I can't step into this method, and I have run out of ideas, I need to see where the fault lies in the code!

The Bridge projects where not originally originally part of the solution, so I added both the projects and have pointed to their PDB symbol files. (The .DLL's are showing as symbols loaded in the modules window.)

I also have "Just My Code" unchecked and all projects in the solution are targetting the .NET 4 Full Profile.

Checked to see if the implementer was using `DebuggerStepperBoundary` or `DebuggerStepThroughAttribute` no such luck.

Any ideas?

Comment: You need to disable `Just my code` in debugging options. I don't know exactly where and at this moment I cannot check anywhere, so I don't post this as answer.

Comment: I really should have included that I have that unchecked in OP, editing.
For anyone who happens across this Q it's in Tools > Options > Debugging > General

Comment: Does your application target the Client Profile?

Comment: @phoog Okay, one of my projects was targeting the .NET2 but I've changed it rebuilt it and switched over the DLL and PDB and unfortunately I am still having the same issue :(

Comment: When you added the bridge projects to your solution, did you change your main project to use project references instead of assembly references?

Comment: @Chris That resolved the problem, thank you :)
Feel a little silly it was something like that but I'm super glad it's working now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the assembly references in your main project to use project references.

This way VS can compile the debug versions of the bridge projects and properly keep track of what's going on so you can step into it.